# On creating table for a reminder app causes null pointer exception on createDailyReminder function

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have a **null pointer exception error** occurred for creating a daily reminder function. To this function I pass two string parameters, one for title and second parameter is a combination of dates separated by commas is appended. Calling the function I got null pointer exception.

The function code is this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
SimpleDateFormat dateParser = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
public static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd";
public static final String TIME_FORMAT = "kk:mm";
public static final String DATE_TIME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss";
public static final String DATE_TIME = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm";

Button for creating reminder.

 createReminder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub


if(positionofSpinner == 1 && position_of_spinnerTime == 1)  
{

String startDateDate =  reminderStartDate.getText().toString();
String endDateDate = reminderEndDate.getText().toString();

Date startDat = null;
    try {
    startDat = sdf.parse(startDateDate);
    System.out.println("The value of startDat = "+startDat);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    Date endDat = null;
    try {
    endDat = sdf.parse(endDateDate);
    System.out.println("The value of endDat = "+endDat);

                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                        System.out.println("The value of SatartDate = "+startDateDate);
                        System.out.println("the value od End date = "+endDateDate);

                        List<Date> days = new ArrayList<Date>();
                        //days.clear();
                        //Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                        mCalendar.setTime(startDat);
                        while (mCalendar.getTime().before(endDat)) {
                            //cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                            mCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,1);



String datval = sdf.format(mCalendar.getTime());

                            days.add(mCalendar.getTime());
                        }

                        System.out.println("Days in the List = "+days);
                         daytoListString = new ArrayList<String>();
                         //daytoListString.clear();
                        for(int i=0 ;i<days.size(); i++)
                        {
                            daytoListString.add(days.get(i).toString());
                        }

                        System.out.println("Days in the daytoListString ="+daytoListString);
                         subStringofDate = new ArrayList<String>();
                         //subStringofDate.clear();
                            for (int i =0; i< daytoListString.size(); i++)
                            {
                                subStringofDate.add(daytoListString.get(i).substring(0, 3));
                            }
                        System.out.println("Day value in the subStringofDate = "+subStringofDate);



                        for (int j=0; j< daytoListString.size(); j++)
                        {
                            System.out.println("The value of daytoListString.get(j) = "+daytoListString.get(j));
                            for(int i =0; i<OptionarrayList.size(); i++)
                            {   
                                OptionarrayList.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));

                                System.out.println("The value of OptionarrayList.get(i) = "+OptionarrayList);
                                if ((daytoListString.get(j).substring(0, 3)).contains(OptionarrayList.get(i)))
                                {
                                    System.out.println("Itz get success");

                                    //DatesNeeded.clear();
                                    DatesNeeded.add(daytoListString.get(j));
                                    System.out.println("The size of DatesNeeded 1123456 = "+DatesNeeded.size());



                                    System.out.println("the array value in the DatesNeeded= "+DatesNeeded); 
                                }
                            }
                        }


                                    //DateWithTimeNeeded.clear();
                                    System.out.println("The size of DatesNeeded = "+DatesNeeded.size());
                                    for(int k = 0;k<DatesNeeded.size(); k++)
                                    {   


                                         //valdate = sdf.format(DatesNeeded.get(k));
                                         //System.out.println("The value of valdate = "+valdate);
                                    //  DateWithTimeNeeded.add(DatesNeeded.get(k)+" "+timeNeedtoAdd);

                                        try {
                                             convertDate = dateParser.parse(DatesNeeded.get(k));
                                            System.out.println("The value of convertDate = "+convertDate);
                                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        } 

                                        valdate = sdf.format(convertDate);
                                        //valdate = dateParser.format(convertDate);
                                        System.out.println("The value of valdate : "+valdate);


                                       // String str = valdate.substring(16, 34);

                                        //System.out.println("value of str = "+str);
                                        System.out.println("The value of timeNeedtoAdd here = "+timeNeedtoAdd);

                                        String timeplus = timeNeedtoAdd+":00";

                                        String v1 = valdate.replace("00:00:00", timeplus);

                                        System.out.println("The value of v1 = "+v1);


                        DateWithTimeNeeded.add(valdate+" "+timeNeedtoAdd);



                                    }

                                    System.out.println("the value of DateWithTimeNeeded = "+DateWithTimeNeeded);
                                    System.out.println("The size of DateWithTimeNeeded array = "+DateWithTimeNeeded.size());

                                                    }

                        System.out.println("The size of DateWithTimeNeeded 123456 = "+DateWithTimeNeeded.size());





                        saveDailywithTime();
                        sendSMSMessage();
                        setResult(RESULT_OK);
                        Toast.makeText(Add_Remainders.this
                                , getString(R.string.task_saved_message)
                                , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        finish();

                    }




//                      saveState();
//                      sendSMSMessage();
//                      setResult(RESULT_OK);
//                      Toast.makeText(Add_Remainders.this
//                              , getString(R.string.task_saved_message)
//                              , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                      finish();
                    }
                });





Its a function for saving the data to sq lite database, In side this the function called createDailyReminder is calling 

public void saveDailywithTime()
    {
        //long id = 0;
        String reminderDailyDateTime = ""; 
        String value = "";
        String title = reminderTitle.getText().toString();
        SimpleDateFormat dateTimeFormat = new 
                SimpleDateFormat(DATE_TIME);





        for (int a=0; a<DateWithTimeNeeded.size(); a++)
        {
             System.out.println("The elements in the DateWithTimeNeeded = "+DateWithTimeNeeded.get(a));
             System.out.println("The size of DateWithTimeNeeded = "+DateWithTimeNeeded.size());
             reminderDailyDateTime += DateWithTimeNeeded.get(a)+",";

             value = TextUtils.join(",",DateWithTimeNeeded);

        }
         System.out.println("The value of reminderDailyDateTime = "+reminderDailyDateTime);
         System.out.println("The value of value = "+value);




        DateandTime = new ArrayList<String>();
        System.out.println("The size of DateWithTimeNeeded= "+DateWithTimeNeeded.size());


        List<String> listofDateWithTime = new ArrayList<String>();

        listofDateWithTime =  Arrays.asList(reminderDailyDateTime.split(","));

        System.out.println(" The values in the listofDateWithTime = " +listofDateWithTime);

         for (int j = 0; j<listofDateWithTime.size(); j++)
         {
             System.out.println("The values in the listofDateWithTime = "+listofDateWithTime.get(j));
         }



         System.out.println("The size of listofDateWithTime = " +listofDateWithTime.size());
        for(int y = 0; y< listofDateWithTime.size(); y++)
        {
            try {
                 datetoadd = dateTimeFormat.parse(listofDateWithTime.get(y));
                 //datetoadd = dateParser.parse(listofDateWithTime.get(y));
                 System.out.println("the value of datetoadd = "+datetoadd);
                 datetoaddtocalander.add(datetoadd);
                 System.out.println("The dates in the datetoaddtocalander = "+datetoaddtocalander);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The size of datetoaddtocalander = "+datetoaddtocalander.size());
        for (int x =0; x< datetoaddtocalander.size(); x++)
        {
            System.out.println("The values in the datetoaddtocalander = "+datetoaddtocalander.get(x));
            mCalendar.setTime(datetoaddtocalander.get(x));
        }
        System.out.println("value of Mcalender = "+mCalendar);
        System.out.println("value of Mcalender getTime = "+mCalendar.getTime());

        String dateTime = dateParser.format(mCalendar.getTime());
        System.out.println("The value of dateTime = "+dateTime);

        System.out.println("The value of mDailyRowId == null = "+(mDailyRowId == null));
        try
        {
        if(mDailyRowId == null) {
            System.out.println("DateWithTimeNeeded 112233 = "+reminderDailyDateTime);
            System.out.println("Ihe value of title is = "+title);

            long id = mDbDailyHelper.createDailyReminder(title, reminderDailyDateTime);
            System.out.println("long id = "+id);


            if(id > 0) {
                mDailyRowId = id;
            }


        } else {
            mDbDailyHelper.updateDailyReminder(mDailyRowId, title, reminderDailyDateTime);
        }

        new ReminderManager(this).setReminder(mDailyRowId, mCalendar);
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


Table Creation


import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DailyReminderDbAdapter {
    private static final String TAG = "Reminder";

    //public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data";
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "dailyReminder";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String KEY_REMINDER_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String KEY_MED_TITLE = "med_name";
    public static final String KEY_DATA_TIME = "reminder_data_time";
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";

    public static DatabaseHelper mDbDailyHelper;
    //public static SQLiteDatabase mDb1;

    //+ KEY_MED_TITLE + " text not null, "

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "" +
            "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " ("
            + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + KEY_REMINDER_TITLE + " text not null, "

            + KEY_DATA_TIME + " text not null);";

    private final Context mCtx;

    public DailyReminderDbAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.mCtx = ctx;
    }

    public DailyReminderDbAdapter open() throws android.database.SQLException {
        mDbDailyHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
        ReminderDbAdapter.mDb = mDbDailyHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        mDbDailyHelper.close();
    }

    public long createDailyReminder(String title,  String reminderDateTime) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_REMINDER_TITLE, title);
        //initialValues.put(KEY_MED_TITLE, medname);
        //reminderDateTime = new ArrayList<String>();
//      for(int i = 0;i < reminderDateTime.size(); i++)
//      {
        initialValues.put(KEY_DATA_TIME, reminderDateTime);
        //}


        return ReminderDbAdapter.mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

//  public long createDailyDailyReminder(String title,  String reminderDateTime) {
//      ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
//      initialValues.put(KEY_REMINDER_TITLE, title);
//      //initialValues.put(KEY_MED_TITLE, medname);
//      
//      
//      initialValues.put(KEY_DATA_TIME, reminderDateTime);
//      
//      
//      
//      return ReminderDbAdapter.mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
//  }
//  


    public boolean deleteDailyReminder(long rowId) {
        return ReminderDbAdapter.mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    public Cursor fetchAllDailyReminders() {
        return ReminderDbAdapter.mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_REMINDER_TITLE, KEY_DATA_TIME} , null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    public Cursor fetchDailyReminder(long rowId) throws SQLException {
        Cursor mCursor = ReminderDbAdapter.mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_REMINDER_TITLE, KEY_DATA_TIME}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null, null, null, null, null);

        if(mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }

        return mCursor;
    }

    public boolean updateDailyReminder(long rowId, String title, String reminderDateTime) {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_REMINDER_TITLE, title);
        //args.put(KEY_MED_TITLE, medname);
//      reminderDateTime = new ArrayList<String>();
//      for(int i = 0;i < reminderDateTime.size(); i++)
//      {
            args.put(KEY_DATA_TIME, reminderDateTime);
    //  }



        return ReminderDbAdapter.mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, ReminderDbAdapter.DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        }
    }


}
```

The Error Occrs Like this

```
04-24 08:23:47.403: W/System.err(850): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-24 08:23:47.403: W/System.err(850):  at com.example.medremainder.Add_Remainders.saveDailywithTime(Add_Remainders.java:2116)
04-24 08:23:47.403: W/System.err(850):  at com.example.medremainder.Add_Remainders$8.onClick(Add_Remainders.java:1776)
04-24 08:23:47.403: W/System.err(850):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
04-24 08:23:47.413: W/System.err(850):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
04-24 08:23:47.413: W/System.err(850):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-24 08:23:47.413: W/System.err(850):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-24 08:23:47.413: W/System.err(850):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-24 08:23:47.413: W/System.err(850):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-24 08:23:47.413: W/System.err(850):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-24 08:23:47.413: W/System.err(850):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-24 08:23:47.423: W/System.err(850):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-24 08:23:47.423: W/System.err(850):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-24 08:23:47.423: W/System.err(850):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-24 08:23:47.443: W/System.err(850): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid destinationAddress
04-24 08:23:47.443: W/System.err(850):  at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:77)
04-24 08:23:47.443: W/System.err(850):  at com.example.medremainder.Add_Remainders.sendSMSMessage(Add_Remainders.java:1867)
04-24 08:23:47.443: W/System.err(850):  at com.example.medremainder.Add_Remainders$8.onClick(Add_Remainders.java:1777)
04-24 08:23:47.443: W/System.err(850):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
04-24 08:23:47.443: W/System.err(850):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
04-24 08:23:47.453: W/System.err(850):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-24 08:23:47.453: W/System.err(850):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-24 08:23:47.453: W/System.err(850):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-24 08:23:47.453: W/System.err(850):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-24 08:23:47.453: W/System.err(850):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-24 08:23:47.453: W/System.err(850):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-24 08:23:47.462: W/System.err(850):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-24 08:23:47.462: W/System.err(850):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-24 08:23:47.462: W/System.err(850):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-24 08:23:47.552: D/ActionBarSherlock(850): [dispatchPostResume]
```

Comment: On Which line you are getting `NPE` ?

Comment: do you debug your app?? post your logcat

Comment: In side the function saveDailywithTime() the line is              long id = mDbDailyHelper.createDailyReminder(title, reminderDailyDateTime);

Comment: the above mentioned is logcat

Comment: Actually i was taking days like Monday Sunday from check box and comparing with calendar.day of week between start date and end date and adding the time to the dates which are Sunday and Monday between start date and end date. The added time and date values is append and save to a string. that string("reminderDailyDateTime") is passed as argument to that function to store string of dates to database and am set the date of that strings to calender fo showing reminder.